# Why does Array<MyType>.find(...) return 'MyType | undefined'?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm building an Angular app using TypeScript. I have the following classes with corresponding interfaces that exactly match the properties:

**Map:**

```
export class Map extends BaseObject implements IMap {
    Dimensions: Dimension[];
    Shapes: Shape[];
    Roles: Role[];
}
```

**BaseObject:**

```
export class BaseObject implements IBaseObject {
    ID: string;
    Label: string;
    DataType: string;
    CreatedDate: Date;
    CreatedUser: string;
    UpdatedDate: Date;
    UpdatedUser: string;
}
```

I have the following service method, where `mapArray()` is a function for mocking up an array of Map objects (the return type is explicitly stated as `Map[]`):

**My Service Method:**

```
getMap(id: string): Observable<Map> {
    return of(mapArray().find(map => map.ID === id));
}
```

The code for this was lifted pretty much wholesale from an [Angular tutorial example](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5#add-heroservicegethero):

**Angular Tutorial Service Method:**

```
getHero(id: number): Observable<Hero> {
  this.messageService.add(`HeroService: fetched hero id=${id}`);
  return of(HEROES.find(hero => hero.id === id));
}
```

The error I have on the `return` line of my service method is this:

> Type 'Observable<Map | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Map>'.

I have downloaded the tutorial sample code and I can confirm that the `.find()` method is returning a type `Hero`, whereas the `.find()` method on my code is returning a type `Map | undefined`.

What would be causing this difference in behaviour?

Comment: `.find` can return undefined because there is always the chance that no item in the array meets your condition. If you're confident that there will always be a result, you can just cast the result to `Map`. EG: `mapArray().find(map => map.ID === id) as Map`. I don't know why the example isn't including undefined it it's return type, unless they manually overrode the `find` type signature somewhere? EDIT: Likely they don't have the `--strictNullChecks` flag set, but you do?

Comment: Well a quick Ctrl+click on the working `find` shows this: `find(predicate: (value: T, index: number, obj: T[]) => boolean, thisArg?: any): T | undefined;`
The plot thickens!

Comment: yeah, I'm guessing that the example project does not have the `strictNullChecks` setting on, but your project does, which would explain this behavior. @basarat's answer should fix your error in that case.

Comment: By heck, you're right @CRice! Adding `"strict":true,` to `tsconfig.json` in the Angular project has it returning `Hero | undefined`. That's it, that was the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What would be causing this difference in behaviour?

the option `strictNullChecks`.

## Why?

Because `Array.prototype.find` *does* return `undefined`

## Fix

If you know that you will definitely find it you can use an assertion:

```
getMap(id: string): Observable<Map> {
    return of(mapArray().find(map => map.ID === id)!);
}
```

## More

- Array.prototype.find : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find
- non-null assertion : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/options/strictNullChecks.html

Comment: Thanks @basarat, it doesn't quite answer the difference in behaviour but your answer made me think about why I'm trying to replicate that behaviour instead of dealing with it properly - that is to say that I should be handling the situation where an item cannot be found for the specified ID.

Comment: ` it doesn't quite answer the difference in behaviour ` The option `strictNullChecks` is the difference mentioned in the answer 

Comment: Thanks for that cheeky edit ;)

For everyone else, this can be set in `tsconfig.json` by setting `"strict": true` under `compilerOptions`.

Comment: Yeah Sorry. I reviewed the answer again after your comment 